retriving id directly from entity by not loading navigation property
so I have 2 entites (Product, Category).
Category contains list of products and each product has its own category.
So in database Product table has category_id column that is foreign key of Category table.
My question is can i create property categoryId in Product class so when I will load my product I will also see categoryId data. Normally to achive that I need to load also category property of my product class. But I don't want to retrive all information about category I need just id.
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "categories")
    public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> products;

    public Category() {

    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integers id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "products")
    public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;
    
    //private int categoryId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    public Product() {

    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription() {
        this.description = description;
    }
}


You mappedBy is using that category field of Product entity. If you only want to retrieve the categoryId, you need to remove that mappedBy first but it will unnecessarily create the extra table.
